# Is there any way to use a URL field across google calendar and ios calendar

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, calendar, google-calendar-api

I want to add a URL to an event on a google calendar through the calendar API. This calendar will often be viewed on a iphone.

Google provide a source field that can be used to link back to the source. Apple provide a URL field in which a URL can be written. But neither of these is shown on the other's platform.

Is there any way of getting either of these to show on the other's platform? Or is there another way of attaching a link to an event? I know that I can write the url in the description (google) or notes (apple) field and this is shown on both platforms, but I was looking for a better way as the description field is already somewhat crowded...

I have tried google for any information, but all I get with relevant search terms are pages to do with syncing between apple and google (source and url are search terms used for that as well)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately Google Calendar doesn't support iCal's URL field, and neither does the API. As you've found, for the time being the description / notes field is your best option.